# The new EA games cannot be found in the Software Center

Tags: software-center, package-management, games

Well, I want to install the two EA games that arrived [in the software Center recently.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/ea-games-arrive-in-the-ubuntu-software-center/) But these packages seem to be missing as in the following picture:

[image]

I've tried to update the sources, and tried to search manually but no luck . And I've tried installing them using the terminal also.

Despite the fact that they are online games, how can I fix this?
I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: My understanding is that they're currently only available for 12.04. Also, are you looking in the "For Purchase" section? You can get there by clicking the arrow next to All Software.

Comment: @Marius: yes , I am on 12.04. And no, I can't find it there also.

Comment: Bug report it. It's broken for me too. They appear if you look in the right place, but they are not in the search.

Comment: @gecko : Where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can still play the games (as [OrangeTux pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/a/134273/2079)), it would be ideal to install these through the Software Center, so that EA can see the strength of the Ubuntu platform.

For now, that seems to be impossible for many users, but you can [subscribe to the bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/997026).

Answer (score 3):

The only thing the installation does is creating a shortcut to the games. The games are browsers games, so no installation is needed.

Here are the links:

[Command and Conquer](http://alliances.commandandconquer.com/intro/index)

[Lord of Ultima](http://www.lordofultima.com/en/welcome/light)

Comment: I know they are just launchers for online games. And I can make them manually. But why I can't find them in the Software Center? This is my problem. Thanks btw

Comment: This doesn't really help, it just bypasses the software center and EA then has no way to measure the success of trying USC as a distribution platform. Better the fix the actual problem so users who try it can be counted!

Answer (score 1):

Search works fine here - `Lord` & `Command` respectively

Comment: Does not work for me ,actually there are other users facing the same problem, as they are saying in [OMG Ubuntu post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/ea-games-arrive-in-the-ubuntu-software-center/).

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Update manager, if there doesn't appear to be any update click Check. After installing those updates go back to Ubuntu Software Center and the games should be there.

Anyway, as they have already said, there are just icons which redirect you to the website.